# Define variable as nonnegative real numbers

Tags: r, variables, intervals

I've been searching online for how I can define x as a vector of nonnegative real numbers in R, but cannot find anything (the search results keep reading R as the real number line, rather than the programming language).

Would anyone be able to tell me how to do this? I'm thinking that it should be something like:

```
 x <- interval(0,inf)
```

Comment: R does not have a base object type for representing this. The [intervals package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/intervals/vignettes/intervals_overview.pdf) might be of use to you; I'm not familiar with it though.

Comment: Some context for why you need this might be helpful. Also, sometimes adding "CRAN" to your search query is effective at obtaining R-related results.

Comment: I simply want to graph a function $y=f(x)$ on the x-y plane. My x-values for the function is valid are nonnegative real numbers. In order to define y, I need to first define x, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The vector you want would be an infinite sequence.
In Python that can be done with generators. You create a generator for that infinite sequence.
In R the package lambda.r do that but it is not straightforward.

The generator can be defined with `seq.gen`. Note that you define the start but not the end.

```
seq.gen(start) %as%
{
  value <- start - 1
  function() {
    value <<- value + 1
    return(value)
  }
}
```

I strongly suggest reading the blog post: 
http://cartesianfaith.com/2013/01/05/infinite-generators-in-r/